# Setting value for Input type="time" on iOS always sets value to current time

Tags: html, ios

I have an HTML document with a button and an input of type time. To set the value of the input to '09:00' either

- Click on the button or
- Set focus on the input

```js
function setTime() {
document.getElementById('timebox').value = "09:00";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Set time" onclick="setTime()"/>

<input type="time" id="timebox" onfocus="setTime()"/>
```

Setting the value via the button always works great.

Setting the value via the focus only works on Windows PC, OSx, and Android. This does not work on **iOS**. We tested with Chrome and Safari. Here the current time is used as the value instead of our '09:00'

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I wonder if using recommended code is better for iOS, otherwise we can try a setTimeout

I also changed the name of the function since setTime could be an existing built-in function on a date element

```js
const setMyTime = () => document.getElementById('timebox').value = "09:00";

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("but")
          .addEventListener("click",setMyTime);
  document.getElementById("timebox")
          .addEventListener("focus", function() { setTimeout(setMyTime,50) });
})
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Set time" id="but"/>

<input type="time" id="timebox" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not work. I am curious what you mean with 'try a setTimeout'.

Comment: `..."focus",function() { setTimeout(setMyTime,10) })`

Comment: Interesting! A timeout works, though 10ms is not enough. A timeout of 50ms is enough whilst not being noticeable/annoying. Dare I ask to elaborate on why it does work now. It seems hacky, and I would like to work towards a proper solution.

Comment: I incorporated the tweak from your comment in the solution

Comment: Unfortunately, the proposed solution doesn't work. I could change the value, but then the time picker would out of sync. I am grateful for your suggestions. They helped steer me in the right direction.